# MySQL auto-increments with no entry

Tags: mysql

I have a database in which I have a Auto_Increment primary key ID as well as a field called MUID. MUID stores 6Byte Hex-ids in varchar and is marked as unique.

When I make a new entry with an MUID that hasnt been there before, everything is fine. On the other hand, if I accidentally try to register the same MUID twice, it doesn't make a new entry (thats what i wanted), but it still increases auto id!

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I believe that happens because the id is incremented when SQL tries to create a new entry. Since it fails to create the entry because of your duplicated MUID no entry is added, but the id is incremented as a safety measure. The only way I know of to stop this is to either disabled auto increment or remove your restriction on the MUID.

Comment: If your MUID is marked as unique, of course it will throw you an error when you try to register the same MUID, that's what the unique property does.

Comment: @benjamin: hmm.. that's not good. I have a whole lot of RFID tags to put into my database and i wrote a function, so that i can store them automatically by just putting it on the reader. If i do one mistake and store one thing twice, everything is ruined? ... edit: i know i could check manually if that entry is there, but this takes too much time.

Comment: @aleation: i know. and that is what i wanted. problem is, auto_id still increases without an entry.

Comment: well I wouldn't say ruined. It really shouldn't matter if you don't have every id filled. When you need to get ids you should be querying the database. I think you will have more luck if you try to adjust your program to account for non-sequential id numbers.

Comment: I assume you want to store the MUID in more than one ID